# asp.net same solution name but under different directories are sync each others

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 1 asp.net solution (name: '123') under 'abc' folder. and I copied solution '123' into 'xyz' folder. After modifying a controller of solution  '123' under 'abc' folder, the same controller of solution '123' under 'xyz' was updated what I changed in 'abc'.

e.g:

I changed a **variable name** of the controller of **solution '123'** under **'abc' folder**.

the **variable name** of the controller of **solution '123'** under **'xyz' folder** was changed.

How can I disable it?

=== updated ====

I created a new solution and Add->existing project. but same happen.

Comment: is it possible , then you can change drive folder.(Copy to another drive)

Comment: @Asif Raza, Thanks for comment. I tried it but I got same result. where ever I copy/paste the project into another folder/drive, those are sync each others.